# ANSI C sscanf giving segfault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf

I am reading a "," delimited CSV file and trying to convert the token to a integer with sscanf and getting segfault error.

Here is my code:

```
#define MAX_LINE_SIZE 1024
#define DELIMITER ','

void load_data(char * coinsfile)
{

   char temp_line[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
   char * token;
   int number_coin;

   while (fgets(temp_line, MAX_LINE_SIZE, coins_file) != NULL) {
      token = strtok (temp_line, DELIMITER);
      while(token != NULL) {
         token = strtok (NULL, DELIMITER);
         sscanf(token, "%d", &number_coin);
      }
   }
}
```

testing CSV file:

```
5,10
10,5
20,8
50,2
100,20
200,8
```

Comment: Show please the whole code that could affect this - including temp_line and coins_File variable declaration and example lines from your csv. But you're not testing token against NULL before sscanf().

Comment: @Constantin I have added requested info
 `coins_file` is the file name for CSV file which comes from another code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This reads from `stdin` instead of an file, but it works without SEGFAULT. Notice the additional check for `token != NULL` before `sscanf()`.

Example Input:

```
12;22;
```

Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_SIZE 1024
#define DELIMITER ";"

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  char temp_line[MAX_LINE_SIZE+1];
  char * token;
  int number_coin;
  while (fgets(temp_line, MAX_LINE_SIZE, stdin) != NULL) {
    token = strtok (temp_line, DELIMITER);
    while(token != NULL) {
      token = strtok (NULL, DELIMITER);
      if(token != NULL)
        sscanf(token, "%d", &number_coin);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong, since you're not passing a NUL terminated string as the second argument to `strtok()`. You're getting undefined behavior for as many times as the input contains characters that are not `';'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define DELIMITER ','
```

Should be:

```
#define DELIMITER ","
```

and:

```
strtok(temp_line, &DELIMITER);
```

should be:

```
strtok(temp_line, DELIMITER);
```

The second argument to `strtok()` should be a NUL terminated string, you're probably getting your segfault because it's not, although passing `NULL` to `sscanf()` per the other answer is also not good. Reversing the order of these two lines:

```
token = strtok (NULL, DELIMITER);
sscanf(token, "%d", &number_coin);
```

may have been what you intended, otherwise you're not reading in the first number on each line. `token` would always be non-`NULL` at the start of the loop, this way.